# Subset sum NP-Completness

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-complete

I know that the subset sum problem is NP-Complete because I can reduce a known NP-Complete problem to subset sum.

However, since subset sum can be solved by dynamic programming, I was not completely convinced that it is NP-Complete. I then realized that the dynamic programming solution in fact tries all possible combinations and because of this, is in fact the same as a brute force approach. Is this a valid insight into why subset sum is NP-Complete?

Answer (score 1):

> tries all possible combinations and because of this, is in fact the same as a brute force approach

You don't share the specific algorithm you have in mind, but [I think you are wrong](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23611/98). Trying all splittings at every level of the recursion is *not* the same as trying all solutions.

> since subset sum can be solved by dynamic programming, I was not completely convinced that it is NP-Complete

Again, you don't share the specific algorithm, but it probably has [pseudo-polynomial running time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time). So no, there is no contradiction; "dynamic programming" does not equal "polynomial time" let alone "fast".