# How to 'memoize' this recursive solution?

Tags: algorithms

I was doing this problem:

```
A move consists of taking a point (x, y) and transforming it to either (x, x+y) or (x+y, y).

Given a starting point (sx, sy) and a target point (tx, ty), return True if and only if a sequence of moves exists to transform the point (sx, sy) to (tx, ty). Otherwise, return False.

    Examples:
    Input: sx = 1, sy = 1, tx = 3, ty = 5
    Output: True
    Explanation:
    One series of moves that transforms the starting point to the target is:
    (1, 1) -> (1, 2)
    (1, 2) -> (3, 2)
    (3, 2) -> (3, 5)

    Input: sx = 1, sy = 1, tx = 2, ty = 2
    Output: False

    Input: sx = 1, sy = 1, tx = 1, ty = 1
    Output: True

    Note:

    sx, sy, tx, ty will all be integers in the range [1, 10^9].
```

I know the solution where you split it up into the ty-tx case, or tx-ty case, and solve it recursively, but I was wondering if there is a DP solution to this. Here is my recursive solution:

```
public boolean reachingPoints(int sx, int sy, int tx, int ty) {
    return help(sx,sy,tx,ty);
}

public boolean help(int sx, int sy, int tx, int ty){
    if(sx==tx && sy == ty){
        return true;
    }
    if(sx>tx || sy>ty){
        return false;
    }
    if(sx==tx){
        if(ty-sy%sx==0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(ty==sy){
        if(tx-sx%sy==0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return(help(sx, sy, tx%ty, ty) || help(sx, sy+sx, tx, ty));
}
```

How would I put this into an array? I have trouble in the memoization part of DP, and I cannot figure this one out.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can solve it recursively, [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2057/755.