# How to master Dynamic Programming?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am having hard times learning Dynamic Programming.

I looked around the web and found many tutorials with examples.

Each time I tried to figure out how to solve a new problem before looking at the solution my mind locked up and I could not continue trying...

I do not where to start!! For example, in divide and conquer I know how to start but In dynamic programming there is no a fixed starting point or at least (technique).

Last try I moved forward but I found that the solution was in a completely different direction.

Comment: Read and understand example and then try, try again. There is no formula. Also, this has been covered before as noted. You might want to browse other questions on [tag:dynamic-programming].

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why I can't just comment.  All I want to do is share a link:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/

Or better yet:  [Deciding on Sub-Problems for Dynamic Programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/645/deciding-on-sub-problems-for-dynamic-programming?rq=1)

This is a duplicate.

Comment: To prevent spam, SE has a policy that prevents new users (less than 50 reputation points) to post comments on someone else's post. The unfortunate side-effect is that valid comments can't be posted.

Comment: To mark as duplicate, you can still flag posts (requires 15 or more points).

Comment: Marked it as a duplicate, as @dhj suggests. Thanks!