# Understanding tables in Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, dynamic-programming

I came across this problem that asks you to implement a regular expression matcher with support for '.' and '*', where

'.' Matches any single character.

'*' Matches zero or more of the preceding element.

```
isMatch("aa","a") → false
isMatch("aa","aa") → true
isMatch("aaa","aa") → false
isMatch("aa", "a*") → true
isMatch("aa", ".*") → true
isMatch("ab", ".*") → true
isMatch("aab", "c*a*b") → true
```

While I was able to solve this in a linear fashion, I came across lots of solutions that used DP, like the one below,

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isMatch(String text, String pattern) {
        boolean[][] dp = new boolean[text.length() + 1][pattern.length() + 1];
        dp[text.length()][pattern.length()] = true;

        for (int i = text.length(); i >= 0; i--){
            for (int j = pattern.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                boolean first_match = (i < text.length() && 
                                       (pattern.charAt(j) == text.charAt(i) ||
                                        pattern.charAt(j) == '.'));
                if (j + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(j+1) == '*'){
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i][j+2] || first_match && dp[i+1][j];
                } else {
                    dp[i][j] = first_match && dp[i+1][j+1];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[0][0];
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding this. I've solved a few DP problems that involved grids (shortest path in 2d grid, largest square in binary 2d grid),  using a DP table there made perfect sense to me. However here I'm completely lost, I'm unable to understand how traversing a 2d table helps in solving this problem. Further more it appears we know when the characters don't match in the loop, so I don't understand why we don't terminate the search there (this is also probably due to my lack of understanding of how a table traversal leads to a solution). Is there a clear intuitive explanation for problems like these?

Comment: Some related questions, maybe even duplicates: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/645/98, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/47216/98, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2057/98. Tl;dr: don't think about the table; think about the recurrence underneath. Coding with a table is the simple part.

Answer (score 3):

`dp[i][j]` represents whether `text[i..]` matches `pattern[j..]`.

If `pattern[j..]` is starting with `x*` for some symbol `x` (including `.`), then `text[i..]` matches `pattern[j..]`, or `x*pattern[(j+2)..]`, if and only if

- `text[i..]` matches `pattern[(j+2)..]` (i.e. `x*` matches an empty string), or
- `text[i]` is `x` and `text[(i+1)..]` matches `x*pattern[(j+2)..]` (i.e. `x*` matches a non-empty string).

This is implemented by this part of code:

```
if (j + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(j+1) == '*'){
    dp[i][j] = dp[i][j+2] || first_match && dp[i+1][j];
}
```

On the other hand, if `pattern[j..]` is not starting with `x*`, `text[i..]` matches `pattern[j..]` if and only if `text[i]` matches `pattern[j]` and `text[(i+1)..]` matches `pattern[(j+1)..]`. This is implemented by this part of code:

```
else {
    dp[i][j] = first_match && dp[i+1][j+1];
}
```